# How to reverse sed output?

Tags: string, unix, shell, sed

I'm reading from a line that's about 500 characters. How can I get sed to, instead of replacing that string with something, replace the rest of the line with something?
In short, I want to remove all the text around a specified string. Deleting columns with awk won't work, because there is an indeterminate amount of characters before and after the matched string.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using back references:

```
sed 's/.*\(searchstring\).*/___\1___/'
```

The `.*`'s around the search string will match everything but the string, and the parentheses tell `sed` to remember what it matched.  You can refer to the first matched string with `\1`.

Here's an example (replacing everything but 'bar baz'):

```
$ echo "foo bar baz qux" | sed 's/.*\(bar baz\).*/___\1___/'
___bar baz___
```

You can replace 'bar baz' with whatever pattern you like in the above; I just used a basic string for simplicity.